# Typescript[ARRAY OF OBJECTS] get value of key on init array

Tags: arrays, typescript

I initialize array of objects in typescript. I want to get id param of particular object what I am initializing.

```
vacancies: Array<Vacancy> = [{
        id: 1,
        is_fav: this.favouritesService.favourites.find(fav => fav === this.id)
    }];
```

Here **this.id** is that particular objects id; this expression gives error. Can I retreive that property there, when initializing?

Comment: <Vacancy> is an interface. And error says that **this.id** does not exist on type of my class.

Comment: Forget favouritesService, in my case, I want to just get id of that particular object. vacancies: Array<Vacancy> = [{
        id: 1,
        is_fav: this.id
    }]; this should be fine too

Comment: I just do not know how to retreive id of that object when initializing

Answer (score 1):

So you have this object literal:

```
{ 
  id: 1, 
  is_fav: this.id 
}
```

The straight-forward answer is NO, you can't access own properties of object literal on initialization. However you *can* access own props from *methods*. So you might use a getter:

```
{ 
  id: 1, 
  get is_fav() { return this.id } 
}
```

Comment: Nope I dont mean that. I mean when I have an object, I want to access objects.id in declaring other key; is_fav should look on id property of that object, not class's object

Comment: Thanks for your provided answer. I have found other way, but still appreciate. Upvote from me. My way was to map that object when initializing and get object.id. Thanks, regards Nick

Comment: Ok, good luck. You should also choose my answer as the best if it answered your question.